# How do I use a conjunction to join two clauses directly after a list of terms?

Tags: conjunctions, lists, disambiguation

I am trying to offer a choice between two options, the first of which has several sub-options. I'm unsure how to express this in a grammatically correct and clear manner.

What I have currently is basically

> Access some data in category one, category two, or category three, or create your own category.

The two main options are "access" or "create", and "access" has options "one, two, or three".

Does this structure make sense as written? If not, how can it be improved for clarity?

Comment: Additional side question: How can I precisely describe the grammar I am trying to use? I wasn't really even sure what to search for to find answers for my question.

Comment: It’s fine as written.

Comment: To make it crystal clear add *alternatively*: “.. or, alternatively, create your own category”

Comment: You can also substitute a dash for the last comma, which sets off what follows.

Comment: A new sentence would work, period before "or create".

Answer (score 1):

You could reword with lettered subdivisions, for example:

> Either (a) access data in category one, two, or three or (b) create
> your own category.

or

> You can choose to (a) access data in category one, two, or three or
> (b) create your own category.

I'm suggesting that *some*  may be unnecessary and that the structure of the sentence may be clearer if *category* isn't repeated. The letters highlight the two verbs, *access* and *create*, preventing any misreading.

Answer (score 0):

The last comma should be replaced with a semicolon, or else it will appear that the portion of the sentence after that comma is just a fourth list item (which it is not).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [***correlative conjunction***](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/correlative-conjunction) ***either... or*** which makes clear what the TWO options are. The problem is that you have two ***or*** which can be confusing. So I would rewrite your sentence in this way:

> ***Either*** access some data in one of the three categories ***or*** create your own (category). [Parenthesis can be omitted].

It is not clear from the OP if there are ***only*** three categories available. If this is the case, than my suggestion stands. If there are more than three categories, than you could use *the **first/last** three categories*, depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to put the list as the second element:

**Create your own category**, or access some data in category one, two, or three.

Comment: I'd say this doesn't work well in this example; sequentiality (try an established category first) should inform style.